# What does the @import mean in sass when it has a property and brackets after it?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to decode the following line...

```
@include button-size($padding-base-vertical, $padding-base-horizontal, $font-size-base, $line-height-base, $border-radius-base);
```

Does anyone know what it means?

I don't understand what the function expression construct is, is it a mixin or something?

Comment: @import or @include?

Comment: Did you even look at the documentation?  Seriously, it is a single page long.  You would have had your answer in 2 seconds.

Comment: Do enlighten me then where is this 'the documentation'? Come on... out with it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that imports can have variables passed, therfore I assume you mean include. Let's assume we have the following mixin:

```
@mixin rotate($degrees: 90deg) {
  transform: rotate($degrees);
}
```

You can include it without a variable; then the default "90deg" is used, but you can override this by passing a parameter in the include. To change this, you can either pass directly a value, or a variable as you did in your example. Valid are:

```
@include rotate(90deg);
@include rotate;

$half: 180deg;
@include rotate($half);
```

For multiple parameters it is also possible to define which one you want to override:

```
@mixin base-font($fontWeight: normal, $fontColor: $mineShaft) {
  color: $fontColor;
  font-weight: $fontWeight;
}

@include base-font($fontColor: $myColor)
```